# I can't create a new user in MySQL, and I can't access it

Tags: mysql, mamp, mysql-error-1045

I have MAMP installed on my mac, and perhaps without realizing it, I must've changed something, because whenever I enter into the terminal:

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql --host=localhost -uroot -    proot
```

I get back:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I have read endless similar posts about people with the same problem, and they're told to create/edit a new user, but I can't do that if I can't get into MySQL using a user with privileges.

I never had any problems accessing MySQL with root with default passwords before today.

Answer (score -1):

Well first off, I have to say, DON'T USE MAMPP. Go ahead and use XAMPP for mac, the problem with using MAMPP is it messes with ports and all that stuff. Also, unless other wise entered your login username should be 'root' and host as 'localhost', with no password.

My advice: look into getting XAMPP

Comment: Old post - but now you can modify the port numbers by selecting which port to use in the admin panel - not that XAMPP isn't great :)